# Oracle dbms_redefinition fails with ora-01749, why?

Tags: oracle, permissions, dbms-redefinition

I ran this as a part of redefining a table

```
DECLARE
  l_num_ers PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.copy_table_dependents(
    uname             => 'myuser',
    orig_table        => 'mytable',
    int_table         => 'redef',
    copy_indexes      => DBMS_REDEFINITION.cons_orig_params, 
    copy_triggers     => TRUE, 
    copy_constraints  => TRUE, 
    copy_privileges   => TRUE, 
    ignore_errors     => FALSE,
    num_errors        => l_num_ers);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_num_ers=' || l_num_ers);
END;
/
```

And got the error

```
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 752
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 1698
```

So how can I solve this?.
The same code worked on another database where the only difference I've found is that the user myuser did not have select right on the table.

I did

```
Select PRIVILEGE, GRANTEE from dba_tab_privs where owner = 'MYUSER' and TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE';
```

To find the differences.

Is the solution to revoke my own privilege to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having SELECT privilege on your own table is unnecessary.

Granting privileges on your own objects added extra rows in the dictionary in earlier versions and it was considered as a bug, fixed in newer releases.

This note decribes this and why redefinition fails becasue of this:

[Bug 8984274 - ORA-1749 Error Running DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS (Doc ID 1345539.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1345539.1)

Just revoke the privilege on your own objects.